# Javascript variable scope inside an ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
        var x = this;
        $.post(some_url, some_data).always(function(){
            var y = x;
            var some_other_data = {
                hi: "hi"
            };
            var posting = $.post(some_other_url, some_other_data);
            posting.done(function (data, b, c) {
                do_something();
            }).fail(function (xhr) {
                var response = xhr.responseText;
                //HERE!
                //y is not defined here!
                //x is defined here!
                //if I get rid of var y = x from above, x is not defined anymore!
                debugger
            });
        });
```

Could anyone give me insight what is going on with the scopes?

Comment: I'm guessing that that `'` is not supposed to be there?

Comment: Not sure what 'this' is and what scope that is in?  Is it in an anonymous function, or global scope?  Try changing `var x= this;` to `var x = 'foo';` as a test?

Comment: I set `var x = 'foo'` and it was lost in the first callback.

Comment: We need to see more code, including the calling of the `new` instance of your Constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing your behaviour in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBsyC/1/)

Which is right, since `x` should be available in any of those scopes.

Can you provide the exact code you're using when you comment out `var y = x`? There has to be something else going on (unless it's something to do with the version of JQuery I guess)

Comment: I see. Apparently it works differently in the console. Try `debugger` instead of `alert()` Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EBsyC/2/

Comment: @MaximusS What browser are you using? I'm getting it just fine in Chrome edit: whoops, somehow posted this on the wrong answer... :S